# Cannot add route

Tags: networking, route

Followed an excellent thread on configuring network settings. Looks like I got the address right (10.10.150.10/24) as I can ping my local interface (10.10.150.10), and the upstream router's address (10.10.150.4) all day long.

But, I have a route for the 10-net, and the 169.254 net only.
pi@harlot:/etc/network $ route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway   Genmask   Flags  Metric   Ref   Use iface
10.10.150.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0   U   0   0   0  eth0
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.0.0   U 0 0   0 eth0
```

Anyway,

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0
FAILS to: SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable.
```

I am obviously missing something....

`/etc/network/interfaces` has what seems to be the right stuff:

```
auto eth0
address 10.10.150.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

A little hazy on bringing interfaces up and down; I did a `sudo ip link set eth0 up` and pings looked good ...

But, no can add the route!! Anybody see the error in my ways?

Using Raspbian (Debian) v. 8 (jessie).

Comment: And the upstream router can ping the 192.168.0.1 fine, and can ping the Pi box's 10.10.150.10 as well. The router has routes everywhere --can ping 4.2.2.2 etc (its a Juniper EX3200 switch w/ vlan interfaces, works great).

Answer (score 3):

How would you reach `192.168.0.1` if you are in `10.10.150.0/24` subnet ?
You should rather have on the pi :
`sudo route add default gw 10.10.150.4 netmask 0.0.0.0 eth0`

Your packets will be routed to the router and the router will send them to 192.168.0.1 if it is configured to.

Comment: Dang, I *figured it out* about 8:30 last night. BEATING myself over missing it.
I needed my next-hop, 10.10.150.4; 192.168.0.1 *could* work on another platform as a qualified-next-hop.
So, Raspberian snarled at me 'cause it had no idea where the heck that subnet was. It was trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Dang, I *figured it out* about 8:30 last night. BEATING myself over missing it.
I needed my next-hop, 10.10.150.4; 192.168.0.1 *could* work on another platform as a qualified-next-hop.
So, Raspberian snarled at me 'cause it had no idea where the heck that subnet was. It was trying to tell me.
I have 3 subnets floating around my LAN; 192.168.0.x is handed out by the far-side of DSL box (of course), Vlan10. Threw in 10.10.150.0/24 and 10.10.160.0/24 to get trunking between Juniper and Cisco. Hadn't touched in a while, threw in some servers this week and brain-locked.
Great group. Apologies!! I am a meat popsicle. LOVE this forum.